# Extraccion de datos de un csv por numero de la semana del año con Python

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

tengo la siguiente casuistica, quisiera extraer la data de un csv que contiene data historica de compras y ventas, pero la extraccion de data la quiero hacer por el numero de la semana del año, ya que mi principal problema es que es mucha data. Ejemplo, tendria como semana de inicio la 20 del 2021 y como semana final la semana actual del año actual o un metodo que pueda dejar extrayendo la fecha actual simpre como "datetime.now()".

```
|fecha_venta|valor|nombre_producto|
|2021-01-01|50.12|papel|
|2021-01-02|51.42|papel|
|2021-01-03|22.22|papel|
|2021-01-04|33.02|papel|
|2021-01-05|44.62|papel|
          .
          .
          .
|2022-03-12|10.52|papel|
|2022-03-13|60.32|papel|
|2022-03-14|80.22|papel|


import pandas as pd
import datetime

datos = pd.read_csv('datos.csv')
df = pd.Dataframe(datos)

#fecha inicio = (Numero de la semana del año, año)
#fecha fin = (Numero de la semana del año, año actual)

#fecha fin posible???? = datetime(datetime.now().year, datetime.now().month, datetime.now().day, 0,0,0)


fecha_inicio = 20, 2021
fecha_fin = ??????

print(df.between_time(fecha_inicio,fecha_fin ))
```

Comment: Hola Odiseo no entiendo bien lo que deseas lograr. Quieres hacer un resumen de las ventas por semana? es decir que las  ventas diarias se sumen y solo tener un registro semanal? Y eso a partir de la semana 20 del año pasado? Hay mas productos aparte de papel y si es asi quieres el resumen por producto?

Comment: O solo quieres filtrar los datos, de modo que tengas todos los registros diarios pero solo a partir de la semana 20 del 2021? O quieres tomar un solo dato de cada semana? Perdona pero no puedo comprender bien

Comment: Hola Rolando Tamayo,quiero extraer del csv todas las columnas pero que sea semana a semana, podiendo ingresarle el numero de la semana del año de donde empiese y hasta donde acabe, que seria la semana actual del año actual.

Comment: O sea quieres separar el dataframe en muchos dataframes más pequeños según la semana?

Comment: @RolandoTamayo basicamente filtrar los datos, de modo que tenga todos los registros diarios pero solo a partir de la semana 20 del 2021. pero que a mi constante le pueda ingresar el numero de la semana de inicio y de fin. Además la de fin que pueda quedarse con un metodo que llame a la fecha actual o semana actual.

Comment: @DanteS. exactamente Dante, como mensione en la descripcion de la consulta es que mi principal problema es que es mucha data la que consulto.

Comment: Odiseo, Te serviría  aplicar el método resamable(?  df_aux.resample(rule = 'M').mean()

Comment: Ok. Ahora creo entender. Primero tendríamos que leer todos los datos como lo hiciste, de ahí crear una nueva variable que indique el numero de semana en la data, filtrar a partir de la semana 20 (aquí también creo iría el año), y después filtrar para fecha inicio fecha fin. Por último tendríamos que filtrar solo la semana actual. Si es así en un rato reviso como se puede lograr.

Comment: @RolandoTamayo lo entendiste bien Rolando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odieso

Primero extraemos la fecha que da inicio a la semana deseada (20,2021) con el método `date.fromisocalendar()`, lo convertimos a `str` para evitar el error de `dtype=datetime64[ns]` y nos queda de la siguiente manera:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

in_year = 2021 ## Año inicial
in_week = 20 ## Semana inicial

fecha_inicio = str(date.fromisocalendar(in_year, in_week,1))

print(fecha_inicio)

2021-05-17
```

Ahora sólo obtenemos la fecha actual con el método `datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` con esto evitamos que incluya el tiempo actual.

```
fecha_fin = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(fecha_fin)

2022-03-17
```

Para realizar el filtrado completo creamos una variable con los datos deseados

`mask = (df['fecha']>=fecha_inicio)&(df['fecha']<=fecha_fin)`

Ahora sólo necesitamos incluirlo en un `loc` y listo, tenemos los datos filtrados.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

## Source
df = pd.read_csv('Odiseo_15.03.csv')

df['fecha']= pd.to_datetime(df['fecha'], dayfirst=True)

in_year = 2021 ## Año inicial
in_week = 20 ## Semana inicial

fecha_inicio = str(date.fromisocalendar(in_year, in_week,1))
fecha_fin = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


mask = (df['fecha']>=fecha_inicio)&(df['fecha']<=fecha_fin)
df = df.loc[mask]

print(df.info(),'\n','\n','\n',df)

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 304 entries, 136 to 439
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------    --------------  -----         
 0   fecha     304 non-null    datetime64[ns]
 1   valor     304 non-null    int64         
 2   nom_prod  304 non-null    object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 9.5+ KB
None 
 
 
          fecha  valor nom_prod
136 2021-05-17      4    Papel
137 2021-05-18      3    Papel
138 2021-05-19      9    Papel
139 2021-05-20      4    Papel
140 2021-05-21      3    Papel
..         ...    ...      ...
435 2022-03-12      3    Papel
436 2022-03-13      7    Papel
437 2022-03-14      7    Papel
438 2022-03-15     10    Papel
439 2022-03-16      4    Papel

[304 rows x 3 columns]
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos